# AndEngine - Getting Center Coordinates of a Sprite

Tags: java, android, opengl-es-2.0, andengine

I have a sprite in my game and I want to get it's center coordinates. The sprite can be rotated though so I can't just get it's x/y coordinates then add half of the sprite's width/height because the getWidth and getHeight methods return the dimensions of the original, unrotated sprite.

I tried getSceneCenterCoordinates() but that for some reason returns the same coordinates for all sprites even if they are nowhere near each other.

Here's a graphic to describe what I want, the red dot is the coordinate I want, and the width/height labels on the right side figure respresent what I WANT the getWidth/Height methods to return (but they don't):
[image]

Comment: I couldn't solve this problem with any predefined functions. I used another turn around by SIN and COS functions, please tell me if you need more classifications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out how to use getSceneCenterCoordinates() properly, which is to hand it a float[]. Here is my solution:

```
float[] objCenterPos = new float[2];
obj.sprite.getSceneCenterCoordinates(objCenterPos);
Log.d(this.toString(),  "Coordinates: ("+objCenterPos[0]+","+objCenterPos[1]+")");
```

Comment: you still have to find the new width or height after performing the rotation. I think this answer is insufficient so, how did you accept it?!

Comment: I also have to take off the sprite size, 

float center[] = pelota.getSceneCenterCoordinates();
      center[0] -= pelota.getWidthScaled()/2; 
      center[1] -= pelota.getHeightScaled()/2;

Answer (score 2):

You can use coordinates transformer

```
final float[] spriteCoordinates = sprite.convertLocalToSceneCoordinates(x,y);
        final float canonX = spriteCoordinates[VERTEX_INDEX_X];
        final float canonY = spriteCoordinates[VERTEX_INDEX_Y];
Sprite sprite_in_fixedpoint_of_the_first_sprite=new Sprite(canonX,canonY,textureregion)
```

Answer (score 1):

Get the minimum and maximum value of all the corners (for both - x and y components).
Then take average from max and min to get middle:

```
middleX = (maxX + minX) / 2
```

Repeat the same for y component.

Answer (score 1):

Consider something like this

```
    Rectangle test = new Rectangle(100, 100, 50, 100, vboManager);
    mainScene.attachChild(test);

    System.out.println("Before RotCtrX = " + test.getRotationCenterX());
    System.out.println("Before RotCtrY = " + test.getRotationCenterY());

    test.setRotation(45);
    System.out.println("After RotCtrX = " + test.getRotationCenterX());
    System.out.println("After RotCtrY = " + test.getRotationCenterY());
```

and the result are

```
System.out(4526): Before RotCtrX = 25.0
System.out(4526): Before RotCtrY = 50.0
System.out(4526): After RotCtrX = 25.0
System.out(4526): After RotCtrY = 50.0
```

AndEngine Entities rotate around the center (unless you change the RotationCenter values), so applying setRotate() will not affect the "center" point location

those "center" points are relative to the Entity, so if you need the actual screen coordinates, you will need to add those to the getX() and getY() values - which BTW also won't change based solely on applying a setRotate()

Comment: When you call getX() and getY() does that return the top-left corner of the sprite? So if it's rotated will it return the purple dot coordinates from my example picture above?